# c++ signal to qml connection for uptade text on the qml window

Tags: c++, qt, qml

I am trying to learn qt and qml and I want to make a small application which can detect an usb device connect or disconnect. I have a C++ file that calls a thread, it is constantly searching for the usb device in the thread. I want the qml window to show "connected" if a usb device is connected or "disconnected" if a usb device is disconnected.

However, I cannot change the text in the qml window with the emit usbCheckChanged(m_usbCheck) command. The connection link in the qml is as follows, and some parts of the code are below.

```
connection {
target: UsbStateDetect
         onUsbCheckChanged:{
             console.log("onUsbCheckChanged")
             console.log("console: ",m_usbCheck)
             label.text = 
             String(myUsbStateDetect.getUsbStateDetect())
         }
     }
```

**main.cpp**

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
#if QT_VERSION < QT_VERSION_CHECK(6, 0, 0)
    QCoreApplication::setAttribute(Qt::AA_EnableHighDpiScaling);
#endif
    QGuiApplication app(argc, argv);

    UsbHotPlug usbHotplug;
    UsbStateDetect usbStateDetect;


    QQmlApplicationEngine engine;


    qmlRegisterType<UsbStateDetect>("usbStateDetect",1,0,"UsbStateDetect");
    engine.rootContext()->setContextProperty("UsbStateDetect",&usbStateDetect);

    const QUrl url(QStringLiteral("qrc:/main.qml"));
    QObject::connect(&engine, &QQmlApplicationEngine::objectCreated,
                     &app, [url](QObject *obj, const QUrl &objUrl) {
        if (!obj && url == objUrl)
            QCoreApplication::exit(-1);
    }, Qt::QueuedConnection);
    engine.load(url);
    QObject::connect(&usbStateDetect,&UsbStateDetect::usbCheckChanged, &usbStateDetect,&UsbStateDetect::getUsbStateDetect);
    //usbStateDetect.setUsbCheck("USB Device Searching");
    return app.exec();
}
```

**UsbStateDetect.h**

```
class UsbStateDetect : public QThread
{
    Q_OBJECT
    Q_PROPERTY(QString usbCheck READ usbCheck NOTIFY usbCheckChanged)

public:
    explicit UsbStateDetect(QObject *parent = nullptr);
    void run();
    bool Stop;

    Q_INVOKABLE QString getUsbStateDetect();
    QString usbCheck() const;

signals:
    void usbCheckChanged(QString m_usbCheck);

private:
    QString m_usbCheck;

};
```

**UsbStateDevice.cpp**

```
UsbStateDetect::UsbStateDetect(QObject *parent):
    QThread(parent)
  ,m_usbCheck("USB Device Searching")
{
    qDebug() << "An instance of UsbStateDetect is created!";
}

void UsbStateDetect::run()
{
        timeval tv;
        tv.tv_sec = 0;
        tv.tv_usec = 5000000;
        while(1){
            if (libusb_handle_events_timeout_completed(NULL, &tv, NULL) == 0){
                if (status_flag == 1){
                    m_usbCheck=("USB Device Connected");
                    qDebug()<<m_usbCheck;
                }
                else if (status_flag == 0){
                    m_usbCheck=("USB Device Removed");
                    qDebug()<<m_usbCheck;
                }
                qDebug()<<"Result: "<< m_usbCheck;
                //emit usbCheckChanged(m_usbCheck);
                this->msleep(100);
            }
        } //end while
}

QString UsbStateDetect::getUsbStateDetect()
{

    qDebug()<<"getUsbStateDetect: "<< m_usbCheck;

    if (status_flag == 1){
        m_usbCheck=("USB Device Connected");
        qDebug()<<m_usbCheck;
    }
    else if (status_flag == 0){
        m_usbCheck=("USB Device Removed");
        qDebug()<<m_usbCheck;
    }
    qDebug()<<"Result: "<< m_usbCheck;

    return m_usbCheck;
}
```

Note: status_flag comes here from another cpp file, that part of the code is working.

Comment: Please post a [mcve]. Let remind you, only the main thread has access to the UI in Qt. If you want GUI functionality, it must be there, and can be only signaled from the thread.

Comment: the `label.text = m_usbCheck` does not work (you probably also get a warning?), private members of a class are not reachable from QML, presumably you return this member from `usbCheck()`, in which case you should do `myUsbStateDetect.usbCheck`. However, it seems you are also returnning this from `calculate()`? (indeed, please post the cpp code as well)

Comment: Thanks for updating, can you clarify where `status_flag` comes from?

Comment: You probably want to `emit usbCheckChanged()` when it has changed

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).